# UIImagePickerView controller is not rotating

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

On click of a button iam navigating to **`UIImagePickerView` controller** where source type is **`UIImagePickerViewcontrollerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`** but its not responding device orientation and it is always in portrait mode. My application supports 2 orientations i.e portrait and portrait up-side down. How can I rotate for both the orientations?

Comment: Implement category for UINavigation controller and over ride rotation methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.
```

It's a bit more work, but you can use the AssetsLibrary framework to access the list of images and create your own image picker.

You can follow this to create your own picker

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/07/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-assets-library-framework/